# Is it even possible to have a melee based class play a range style in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 1 and 2, you had the freedom to equip both ranged and melee weapons on your character. For example, I could equip a bow or a sword/shield on my paladin. Early in Diablo 3, you can equip a skill to both mouse buttons. This effectively relegates your weapon to a bunch of numbers, as you don't actually attack with it.

Is the only option to create a ranged monk or barbarian to fool the skill system?

Comment: Whoops, ignore previous comment, I misread :D

Comment: @James I understand that the skills are based off of weapon sets, hence relegating your weapon to a bunch of numbers. But I am curious if you can have a melee character use a range build.

Comment: Can you equip ranged weapons on barb or monk? If you can answer this question, then the answer just reveals itself. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Barbarians and Monks cannot equip ranged weapons, so the answer is no.